# using require in layer.conf in yocto

Tags: layer, yocto, bitbake

Considering all freedom that yocto gives to the developer, I have a question.
I would like to make this my_file.inc available only for recipes in one particular meta-layer. I know, that, for instance, using INHERIT keyword inside the local.conf will make my_class.bbclass file available globally for each recipe.

Is it a good practice to add this:

```
require my_file.inc
```

inside layer.conf? Or should I change my_file.inc to the my_file.bbclass, and, add INHERIT = "my_file.bbclass" to the layer.conf?
Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if it seems to work, neither of your approaches is technically completely correct. The key point is that all `.conf` files are parsed first and everything they contain is globally visible throughout the whole build process. So if you add something through the `layer.conf` file, itis not being pulled in through an unexpected place, it also is not being limited that layer only and might therefore cause breakage at other places.

While I do not have a really good and clean solution, maybe the following can help you:

You can make your custom recipes react on certain keywords in `DISTRO_FEATURES` or `MACHINE_FEATURES`. Then you can create a two-staged approach:

1. Add the desired keyword in `local.conf` (or your `MACHINE`, or `DISTRO`, or whatever configuration)
2. Make the recipes react to it. If you need the mechanism in several places, then it might be useful to pour it into a `.bbclass` that your layer brings along and that you pull in for the respective recipes.

This way the effect is properly contained.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe part [5.1.3.2](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#avoid-duplicating-include-files) from the Yocto Project answers your question:

> Avoid duplicating include files. Use append files (.bbappend) for each recipe that uses an include file. Or, if you are introducing a new recipe that requires the included file, use the path relative to the original layer directory to refer to the file. For example, use require recipes-core/package/file.inc instead of require file.inc. If you're finding you have to overlay the include file, it could indicate a deficiency in the include file in the layer to which it originally belongs. If this is the case, you should try to address that deficiency instead of overlaying the include file. For example, you could address this by getting the maintainer of the include file to add a variable or variables to make it easy to override the parts needing to be overridden.

So to avoid duplicate inclusion later, it would be better not to include your `.inc` file(s) this way.

Comment: While this is technically absolutely fine, the `.bbappend` mechanism is not available for `.conf` files. So a slightly different approach might be needed here.